# plt.bar() only shows the first ten elements of list

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to draw a simple bar chart using matplotlib. The problem is that chart does not show all the list i pass to the function, but only the first ten! I do not know why it do so. I test plt.bar() with some range function and it shows more than ten elements but in my case does't. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tiks_pos = ['_', 'T', 'h', 'e', 'S', 'p', 'c', 'i', 'a', 'l', 'O', 'n', 's', 'o', 't', 'm', 'y', 'u', 'E', 'C', 'F', 'K', 'r', 'j', 'w', 'f', 'b', 'Z', '2', 'H', 'd', '4', 'x', '3', 'L', 'v', 'B', 'J', 'g', 'k', 'q', 'I', '1', '6', 'A', '0', '9', 'D', 'P', '8', 'N', 'z', 'R', 'M', 'V', 'Y', '7', 'U', '5', 'G', 'W', 'Q', 'X']
values_pos = [104458, 36841, 248624, 783618, 58924, 109163, 220280, 568591, 778772, 423608, 16913, 479862, 418595, 411700, 340682, 230223, 234610, 183385, 27065, 44234, 18769, 29109, 454000, 66966, 73825, 77058, 143518, 5371, 51593, 21163, 196194, 25891, 67505, 37884, 46189, 71464, 42399, 35453, 132439, 152017, 8861, 17414, 68312, 21182, 48339, 49440, 35749, 35036, 22948, 37348, 26011, 65667, 33479, 59952, 10066, 8504, 29947, 6614, 20050, 23536, 12898, 2513, 7307]
plt.bar(tiks_pos, values_pos)
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: Would you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @user2314737, i provided.

Comment: I get: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'`

Comment: @Anton vBR, in what line? i didn't get an error.

Comment: @keramat Line 4. The only line that can give error tbh.

Comment: My matplotlib backend returns on this line: "ValueError: could not convert string to float"

Comment: @Anton vBR, What is your editor?

Comment: This is a bug in matplotlib. For single letter categories it will limit its functionality to 10 items.

Comment: As shown in the answer to the duplicate. `plt.bar(list(range(len(tiks_pos))), values_pos); plt.xticks(list(range(len(tiks_pos))), tiks_pos)`

Comment: I handled it: tiks_pos = ["'{0}'".format(x) for x in tiks_pos].